# Snapping window has negative value of Left property

Tags: wpf

I have an issue where I snap the window to the left and after I close the window I will save the location (Left, Top) along with size of the window. Next time the window is loaded I will *try* to apply the location and size.

I say *try* because the window might have been viewed on a screen that has larger resolution so it might not be visible at all on our new screen. What I do is - I see if the window(after I apply location and size) fits in the screen. If it doesn't I will show it on the center and if it does, well it's already where I want it.

My issue is when I snap window to the left. The actual Left property is not 0(zero) but -6.something. I suspect this is because the window has shadow around it so the location must be in minus so the actual form(the one with border) is touching left part of the screen. Because of my logic I will get this screen in the center.

**Is there a bullet proof way of determining that the form is snapped to one of the sides?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a bullet proof way of determining that the form is snapped to one of the sides?

No, I don't think so. There is at least no "IsSnapped" property or similar that you can use.

You will have to rely on the `Left` value and adjust it based on the difference in size between the different screens that are involved I am afraid.